# Вывод данных из списка List<> значений типа Struct

Tags: c#, list, struct

сделал код для выполнения следующих действий: пользователь вводит данные в массив переменных типа struct с клавиатуры терминала; упорядочивает значения в массиве (по названию);выводит данные из массива переменных типа struct на устройство отображения.
А как это все переделать в список List<> не понимаю: вводит данные в поля переменной типа struct с клавиатуры терминала и заносит их в список List<>; упорядочивает значения в списке (по названию);выводит  данные  из  списка List<> значений типа struct на устройство отображения.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Book [] v = new Book[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Цена = ");
                v[i].Price = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Название = ");
                v[i].Title = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Автор = ");
                v[i].Author = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            foreach (Book x in v)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
            }
            Array.Sort(v);
            foreach (Book x in v)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
            }
        }

struct Book : IComparable
    {
        public int Price;
        //Поле для хранения цены.
        public string Title;
        //Поле для хранения названия.
        public string Author;
        //Поле для хранения автора.
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Book other = (Book)obj;
            return string.Compare(this.Title, other.Title);
        }

        //Метод для преобравания структуры в строку.
        override public string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} \t {1} \t {2}", Price, Title, Author);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Что-то я вопроса не понимаю. `А как это все переделать в список List<>` - в чем трудность то? Меняете всякие `Book []` на `List<Book>`, добавляете в коллекцию что надо с помощью `.Add()`, вроде все понятно и просто, не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        List<Book> v = new List<Book>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Book b;
            Console.Write("Цена = ");
            b.Price = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Название = ");
            b.Title = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Автор = ");
            b.Author = Console.ReadLine();
            v.Add(b);
        }
```

Comment: Оу, все так просто оказалось, спасибо огромное, все понял

Comment: извините, как сюда добавить сортировку?

Comment: @Kroo_ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort

Comment: @Kroo_ вызвать `v.Sort()`.

Comment: @aepot да, спасибо, уже разобрался))